# Difference between NOW(), SYSDATE() & CURRENT_DATE() in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, datetime

What difference between `NOW()` , `SYSDATE()` , `CURRENT_DATE()` in MySQL and where it can be used in real scenario .

I tried `NOW()`,`SYSDATE()`,`Current_Date()` when I insert data into a table and column datatype is `TIMESTAMP` all are given same date and time.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`CURRENT_DATE()`: will only give you the date.
`NOW()`: give you the datetime when the statement,procedure etc... started.
`SYSDATE()`: give you the current datetime.
Look at the seconds after waiting 5 seconds between `now()1` `sysdate()1` with the following query (scroll to the right):

```
select now(),sysdate(),current_date(),sleep(5),now(),sysdate();

-- will give
-- now()                 sysdate()              current_date()          sleep(5)    now()1                sysdate()1
-- 6/10/2014 2:50:04 AM  6/10/2014 2:50:04 AM   6/10/2014 12:00:00 AM   0           6/10/2014 2:50:04 AM  6/10/2014 2:50:09 AM
```

Comment: Hi, what is said here is true.

A precision however: the "sysdate_is_now" option changes this behavior. When enabled, 'SYSDATE' is strictly equivalent to the MySql keyword 'NOW'.


See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_sysdate-is-now

Answer (score 13):

`NOW()` returns a constant time that indicates the time at which the statement began to execute. (Within a stored function or trigger, `NOW(`) returns the time at which the function or triggering statement began to execute.) This differs from the behavior for `SYSDATE()`, which returns the exact time at which it executes.

```
mysql> SELECT NOW(), SLEEP(2), NOW();
+---------------------+----------+---------------------+
| NOW()               | SLEEP(2) | NOW()               |
+---------------------+----------+---------------------+
| 2006-04-12 13:47:36 |        0 | 2006-04-12 13:47:36 |
+---------------------+----------+---------------------+

mysql> SELECT SYSDATE(), SLEEP(2), SYSDATE();
+---------------------+----------+---------------------+
| SYSDATE()           | SLEEP(2) | SYSDATE()           |
+---------------------+----------+---------------------+
| 2006-04-12 13:47:44 |        0 | 2006-04-12 13:47:46 |
+---------------------+----------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

Current_date returns the time stamp of the client while sysdate returns the time stamp of the server. If both server and the client are on the same machine, then, the result of both commands are the same. But in case that your sever is for example in USA and your clients are in China, then, these two functions return completely different results.

I don't know about thew now(), sorry :-)

Answer (score 2):

One of the major differences between `sysdate()` and `now()` recently bit me in the behind.  It was the difference in the point-in-time and frequency of their execution.  `sysdate()` is evaluated *every time* within the same statement--ie, in every row to which it applies.  But `now()` will only be evaluated *only once, which is at the start of query execution*.

This difference isn't noticeable when there are only a few rows.  But it's very significant when there are millions of rows.  In RHEL7, for example, `sysdate()` apparently makes a costly system call, so that when there are millions of rows, using `sysdate()` took more than an hour, but using `now()` in the exact same statement took only several seconds!

This is on top of precision issues, because `sysdate()` will return a different value, for example, between time t and time t+50 millis.

With regard to `curdate()`, I was also wondering how it's different from either `now()` or `sysdate()`.  The MySQL Reference says that, with regard to when and how many times it's executed, `curdate()` behaves like `now()`.

Reference: [MySQL 5.7 Reference - Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) -- All of the above is described in this page.  However, it's scattered on the page, so you'll have to read through the overview section as well as the reference for each function.

Answer (score 1):

`CURRENT_DATE()` is a synonym for many other similar functions all of which provide only the **date**.
There is a subtle difference between `NOW()` and `SYSDATE()` which you can read up more on this 
[*official MySQL website*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) page.

Answer (score 0):

CURRENT_DATE is static and works better with date indexes.

NOW() *seems* dynamic and does not benefit from index.  (I would love to hear a comment on the subject with more detail on the MySQL internals here!)

Here's a real-world example using `NOW()`:

```sql
explain SELECT DISTINCT e.manager_id, m.manager_name FROM events e JOIN manager m ON m.manager_id = e.manager_id
    WHERE m.manager_name != '' AND e.event_when > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR;
+---------+----------+------------------------------+
| rows    | filtered | Extra                        |
+---------+----------+------------------------------+
| 1333648 |    29.06 | Using where; Using temporary |
|       1 |    90.59 | Using where                  |
+---------+----------+------------------------------+
```

You can see the number of rows are reduced substantially using `CURRENT_DATE` (or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`):

```sql
explain SELECT DISTINCT e.manager_id, m.manager_name FROM events e JOIN manager m ON m.manager_id = e.manager_id
   WHERE m.manager_name != '' AND e.event_when > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 YEAR;
+--------+----------+----------------------------------------+
| rows   | filtered | Extra                                  |
+--------+----------+----------------------------------------+
| 361470 |   100.00 | Using index condition; Using temporary |
|      1 |    90.59 | Using where                            |
+--------+----------+----------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score -2):

NOW() returns a constant time that indicate's the time at which the statement began to exicute whereas SYSDATE () returns the time at which it exicute... OR  in other words NOW ()shows query exicution time and SYSDATE() shows self exicution time..