# Check if date in database is bigger then today

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

So I have a table in my database with reservations.
In Java I only want to show the reservations of today and beyond.

```
PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(
                "SELECT reservatieID,klanten.voornaam,klanten.achternaam,kamerID,startDatum,eindDatum "
                + "FROM reservatie "
                + "INNER JOIN klanten ON reservatie.klantID = klanten.klantID"
                + "WHERE eindDatum =>?");
String now = basisLogin.getDate();
statement.setString(1, now);
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
```

So this is my code. The string of today's date is in this format: yyyy-MM-dd

This is the error I get:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have anerror in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL   server version for the right syntax to use near 'eindDatum >'2017-03-07'' at line 1
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want to use `PreparedStatament#setDate` instead of `PreparedStatament#setString`, and pass in a `java.sql.Date` value that you get by converting your `String` value.

Comment: You need to pass a Date object not a String object.

Comment: Operator is `>=`, not `=>`, and you're missing a space before `WHERE`.

Comment: It works now. Thank you all!

Answer (score -3):

Use one of the functions described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24137752/difference-between-now-sysdate-current-date-in-mysql), depending on if you want to include time.

For example:

```
...WHERE eindDatum => Current_date()");
```

Comment: The code is fine as is and complies so there is no syntax error.  It's a runtime error from attempting to use a string with a date column.

Comment: The Java code may compile, but it's a syntax error in the SQL. So says the runtime exception (`MySQLSyntaxErrorException`). That SQL is not *fine*.

Comment: The cause was ultimately from mixing string with date, reported as that type of exception. Plus, String now = basisLogin.getDate() and statement.setString(1, now); are unnecessary.

Comment: So you're claiming that the **syntax error** is caused by the comparison of valid column name `eindDatum` with the valid string literal `'2017-03-07'`, and not by the incorrect use of `=>` (which should be `>=`) or the missing space in `ON reservatie.klantID = klanten.klantIDWHERE eindDatum =>'2017-03-07'`? Sorry, but you're wrong. It's definitely the missing space before `WHERE` that is the main problem, as I've already [said in a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42654158/check-if-date-in-database-is-bigger-then-today-java-sql/42654334?noredirect=1#comment72434487_42654158).

Answer (score -3):

Use:
WHERE eindDatum => CURDATE()