# Can I compare datetime directly with date? (records created today)

Tags: sql, mysql

I've got such condition for selecting records made today:

```
created_at > CURDATE()
```

where created_at is a datetime.
It's not made by me and generally it works, but client reports that it doesn't give correct results always.
Now I wonder if it's a proper solution and good practice or must it be changed to "DATE(created_at) = CURDATE()"?
So in summary, can datetime be compared with date if we want to fetch records created after specific date? Will SQL process it properly or must it be cast to a date first?

Comment: `but client reports that it doesn't give correct results always.`  Please try to find the incorrect results.   Do know that `created_at > CURDATE()` is the same as `created_at > '2023-10-21 00:00:00'`  (when today is 21 oktober)

Comment: @Luuk That's what I wanted to hear, if it's exactly the same and there are no side effects if I want to get just today's records then it's working fine

Comment: Except for the first second of the data ....   (when time part of that datetime field is equal to `00:00:00`)

Comment: You're right there  But that's not a problem in my case. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, this works in MySQL just as in other DBMS. (Despite their docs on [curdate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) and [type conversions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html), by the way, telling us that `CURDATE()` doesn't return a date, but a string or eight-digit-number, and that the implcit conversion will turn the datetime into a number, too, which would be 14 digits, so a datetime would always be greater than a date.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: no, [curdate()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) returns a date, not a string.

Comment: @Luuk: Well, they do say "Returns the current date as a value in 'YYYY-MM-DD' or YYYYMMDD format, depending on whether the function is used in string or numeric context." This is a string or a number. A date doesn't even have a format, you would have to use `DATE_FORMAT` to get a date in a particular format.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: But `create table d as select curdate();` see: https://dbfiddle.uk/Yj1VsI8M shows a date, and not a `char(10)`. But still it can be implicitly converted to ....

Comment: @Luuk: Yes, all I say is their docs are wrong, which you just proved. They imply that `CURDATE` returs a string or number, which is wrong, as you have just shown. And they say that they will convert both values into approximate numbers (doubles) in order to compare them, which is wrong, too.

Comment: But no point in filing a bug, because there is a too long list to be solved already  (see, for example:m the almost 2 year old:  https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=105783 )

Comment: I could not resist, though :-)  https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=112792

Comment: this post can also help you in understanding the differences among NOW, CURRENT_DATE, SYSDATE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24137752/difference-between-now-sysdate-current-date-in-mysql